# Command Design Pattern simple GUI null pointer

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns, command-pattern

I have these classes: a JPanel extension, an interface and 3 x JmenuItem classes.

```
public class RedFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener {
private JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private JPanel jPanel1;
private fileExitCommand jMenuItem3;
private fileOpenCommand jMenuItem2;
private btnRedCommand jMenuItem1;
private JMenu jMenu1;

/**
 * Auto-generated main method to display this JFrame
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            RedFrame inst = new RedFrame();
            inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            inst.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public RedFrame() {
    super();
    initGUI();
}

private void initGUI() {
    try {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        {
            jPanel1 = new JPanel();
            getContentPane().add(jPanel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
        {
            jMenuBar1 = new JMenuBar();
            setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);
            {
                jMenu1 = new JMenu();
                jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);
                jMenu1.setText("Meniu");
                {
                    jMenuItem1 = new btnRedCommand(jPanel1, "RED");
                    jMenu1.add(jMenuItem1);

                }
                {
                    jMenuItem2 = new fileOpenCommand("Open");
                    jMenu1.add(jMenuItem2);

                }
                {
                    jMenuItem3 = new fileExitCommand("Exit");
                    jMenu1.add(jMenuItem3);

                }
            }
        }
        jMenuItem1.addActionListener(this);
        jMenuItem2.addActionListener(this);
        jMenuItem3.addActionListener(this);
        pack();
        setSize(300 * 16 / 9, 300);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // add your error handling code here
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
     Execute();

}

 }
```

And

```
public class btnRedCommand extends JMenuItem implements Command {

protected JPanel p;
protected String text;

public btnRedCommand(JPanel p, String text) {

    p.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    this.setText(text);
}

public void Execute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    p.setBackground(Color.red);
}

}
```

and

```
public interface Command  {

public void Execute();

}
```

I want the Execute method which is implemented in the 3 JMenuItems to be called depending on which jMenuItem from Menu was selected. How can I properly do this? Do I need a wrapper class for the 3 jMenuItems?

Comment: Add a specific ActionListener to each menu item (3 different ActionListeners in total), and forget about Command. You don't need an abstraction layer if the code you have to execute just changes the GUI.

Comment: @ignis want to do this in order to understand how it is done, the GUI is just for demonstration.

Comment: Yay, that's how it is done. 3 different tasks, 3 different listeners. And no Command interface unless you have to deal with an external class that does some application logic.

Comment: But let's absurdly suppose you'll use the command pattern, how would you do it?

Comment: Your code is very confusing to me as you're using non-standard naming conventions and you seem to have code blocks for no reason. Also, will this line compile, `Execute();`? I don't seen a method to match this. Consider editing your code such that method names all start lower case, class names all start upper case, blocks are used where they should be used, etc... and we'll all have an easier time understanding it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks for the interest. Problem solved. Noted your advice regarding naming convention and blocks. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pattern is overkill here for these simple GUI tasks, but in your `ActionListener`, you could do:

```
Command command = (Command) event.getSource();
command.Execute();
```

**Explanation:** As each of custom `JMenuItem` implements the `Command` interface, they can be cast as such & thereby avail of the `Execute` method.

The reason that an `NullPoinerException` is occurring is that the `JPanel` instance is not assigned in the `Command` constructor:

```
public btnRedCommand(JPanel p, String text) {
   this.p = p;
   ...
```

Comment: I get a NULL pointer exception in the btnRedCommand's Execute method. How do I pass the reference to the JPanel ? Im using this simple GUI just for demonstration.

Comment: Amazing! this.p=p beautiful! I learned something new today! Thanks! Everything works fine now. Can you explain a bit the other 2 lines of code. Since Command is an interface, what's happening there? I see it is not instantiation.

Comment: The instantiation you speak of takes place when you create the menu items.

Comment: Yes, never saw an "Interface = (Interface) ..." until now! Thanks for the new knowledge! I have a starting point here